# Migrate data from Magento 2 to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have a brand new installation of Magento 2.4 and I would like to migrate all data I have from my current installation of Magento 2.1 without all the mess that third-party modules created in the database and unnecessary tables and attributes.

I would like to migrate, work in the new store and when everything is done, migrate again just the customers with passwords, reviews, orders, products without overriding configs, promos, pages and blocks in the new setup.

How could I migrate from Magento 2 to Magento 2?

Does the [Magento Migration tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) work from Magento 2 to Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

**Steps :**

**->** Make the dump file for the current database of 2.4, and the dump file for previous database of 2.1

**->** Make a new database (empty) and then reimport the database of 2.1 to this one.

**->** And then Make the changes in env.php file of magento 2.4 and connect this database to your current magento 2.4 *(connecting the 2.1 database to the magento 2.4)*.

**->** After that Run the commands, Setup:upgrade, Compile, and deploy

After successfully running the commands, You have the data uptodate with the previous version.

**NOTE :** you have the dump file for the magento 2.4 db , so if any issue or exception occur just revert it, preventing the data loss.

*I have tried this and it worked for me (2.3 to 2.4). Let me know if it works for you.*

Comment: This method keeps all the mess from the previous installation and overrides any config I have in my current installation.

Comment: Ok, I will dig into it more and post it here if I found something usefull.